# rows to column transpose for strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the sample data:

```
╔═══════╦════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ Login ║   User_type    ║ Type_login_value ║
╠═══════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ x     ║ assignee_ids   ║ a                ║
║ x     ║ subscriber_ids ║ b                ║
║ x     ║ subscriber_ids ║ c                ║
║ x     ║ subscriber_ids ║ d                ║
║ x     ║ subscriber_ids ║ e                ║
║ x     ║ subscriber_ids ║ f                ║
║ y     ║ assignee_ids   ║ g                ║
║ y     ║ subscriber_ids ║ h                ║
║ y     ║ subscriber_ids ║ i                ║
║ y     ║ subscriber_ids ║ j                ║
╚═══════╩════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

output should be like

```
Login  assignee_ids  subscriber_ids
x      a             b,c,d,e,f
y      g             c,h,I,j
```

There will be some other columns also for grouping. Please suggest what should be the best way to tackle this.

Comment: What is your question? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Couldnt get the formatting right earlier. Sorry for that. I have edited the question now.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server

Comment: @king.code I thought about using Pivot but couldnt figure how to without using aggregation.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I didn't know about FOR XMl. This will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT LOGIN,
       USER_TYPE,
       Stuff((SELECT ',' + TYPE_LOGIN_VALUE
              FROM   #TEMP A
              WHERE  A.LOGIN = B.LOGIN
                 AND A.USER_TYPE = B.USER_TYPE
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS COL1
FROM   #TEMP B ) AB
PIVOT (MAX(COL1) FOR USER_TYPE IN ([assignee_ids],[subscriber_ids])) PV
```

Comment: Hi Paul Thanks for your answer.I used following query to get the result:


select b.user_login,b.user_map_type1,b.user_map_type2,b.user_login_value as 'Assignee',
stuff( 
  (select ',' + a.user_login_value

from #t1 a 
   where a.user_login=b.user_login and a.sys_prefix=b.sys_prefix and a.user_map_type1=b.user_map_type1 and a.user_map_type2=b.user_map_type2
  for xml PATH('')
       ),1,1,''
  ) as 'Subscribers'

from #t2 b